# A rather odd number sequence!

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence, sequence

Can you find the next number in this baffling sequence?

925, 955, 1040, 1140, 1255, 225, 410, ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The next term is:

> **610**

As these terms are to be read as:

> **Times** on a clock, the interval between each one increasing by 15 minutes:
>
>  9:25
>  *+30 mins*
>  9:55
>  *+45 mins*
>  10:40
>  *+60 mins*
>  11:40
>  *+75 mins*
>  12:55
>  *+90 mins*
>  2:25
>  *+105 mins*
>  4:10
>  ***+120 mins***
>  **6:10**
>
>  The next term requires an interval of 105+15=120 minutes, or 2 hours, making it 6:10 (or '610' in the colon-less format of the puzzle).